Vuetify change steps Icon shape
I need to change the shape of Vuetify's step icon. Is there any way to do it? I need large rectangles with rounded corners. I also need to change the text inside the steps. This is my current component.
Thanks.

The CSS for a rectangle with rounded borders is simply having your width greater than your height, with some border-radius.  example
